# What does the "update" element do in Magento layout XML?

Tags: layout, magento

Right now I'm exploring the internals of the admin section of Magento and I stumbled on this piece of XML:

File: `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/catalog.xml`, around line 55

```
50            <block type="core/template" template="catalog/wysiwyg/js.phtml"/>
51        </reference>
52    </adminhtml_catalog_product_new>
53    
54    <adminhtml_catalog_product_edit>
55        <update handle="editor"/>
56        <reference name="content">
57            <block type="adminhtml/catalog_product_edit" name="product_edit"></block>
58        </reference>
```

What does the `<update />` tag do?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The `<update>` basically pulls in another handle.

Assume you have this:

```
<layout>
   <foo>
      <reference name="header">
          <block type="cms/block" name="some_block" as="someBlock">
              <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>some_block</block_id></action>
          </block>
      </reference>
      <reference name="left">
          <block type="cms/block" name="some_totally_different_block" as="someTotallyDifferentBlock">
              <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>some_totally_different_block</block_id></action>
          </block>
      </reference>
   </foo>
   <bar>
      <update handle="foo" /> 
      <reference name="header">
          <block type="cms/block" name="some_other_block" as="someOtherBlock">
              <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>some_other_block</block_id></action>
          </block>
      </reference>
   </bar>
</layout>
```

The resulting XML for `bar` would be:

```
<layout>
   <bar>
      <reference name="header">
          <!-- Start of part pulled in from foo -->
          <block type="cms/block" name="some_block" as="someBlock">
              <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>some_block</block_id></action>
          </block>
          <!-- End of part pulled in from foo -->
          <block type="cms/block" name="some_other_block" as="someOtherBlock">
              <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>some_other_block</block_id></action>
          </block>
      </reference>
      <!-- Start of part pulled in from foo -->
      <reference name="left">
          <block type="cms/block" name="some_totally_different_block" as="someTotallyDifferentBlock">
              <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>some_totally_different_block</block_id></action>
          </block>
      </reference>
      <!-- End of part pulled in from foo -->
   </bar>
</layout>
```

**tl;dr:** The `update` handle is basically a "merge this layout with my current layout".

Answer (score 8):

This handle is used for merging existing layout handles to your current layout.
In your example `<update handle="editor"/>` will add to the `<adminhtml_catalog_product_edit>` following content:

```
<editor>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="setCanLoadExtJs"><flag>1</flag></action>
        <action method="addJs"><script>mage/adminhtml/variables.js</script></action>
        <action method="addJs"><script>mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/widget.js</script></action>
        <action method="addJs"><script>lib/flex.js</script></action>
        <action method="addJs"><script>lib/FABridge.js</script></action>
        <action method="addJs"><script>mage/adminhtml/flexuploader.js</script></action>
        <action method="addJs"><script>mage/adminhtml/browser.js</script></action>
        <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/window.js</script></action>
        <action method="addItem"><type>js_css</type><name>prototype/windows/themes/default.css</name></action>
        <action method="addItem"><type>js_css</type><name>prototype/windows/themes/magento.css</name></action>
    </reference>
</editor>
```

("editor" handle is defined in `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/main.xml`)

Comment: How will Magento know that <editor> handle is inside main.xml ? What if another custom xml file contains <editor> handle? Will that also be merged ?

Comment: I think Magento will merge those two handles.

Comment: Hmmm does that mean Magento will search all the xml files in layout folder for the <editor> handles ? Sorry but not quite understanding it.

Comment: @HashidHameed XML files are all loaded and parsed already at this point.

Comment: @rahmanisback How is it possible that all XML files are parsed at the time executing update handler, since that itself is an xml element which is yet to be parsed ?

Comment: When the app starts the controller action, the tree of layouts has already been loaded then when magento loads the handles to build the XML layout to the view and find an `update` node, it searches in the tree the handle referenced by this node and uses its configuration.